# Check an array value exists another array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays with the following values,

***First Array:***

```
Array
(
    [Strongly Agree] => 100
)
```

***Second Array:***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Strongly Agree
    [1] => Agree
    [2] => Neither Agree or Disagree
    [3] => Strongly Disagree
)
```

I need the output should like this,

```
Array (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
   $temp = array_key_exists($value, $array2) ? $array1[$value] : 0;
   $newArr[$key] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: This needs improvement desperately. For one it will produce `null` instead of zeroes, and it will also emit notices. Don't use code like this.

Comment: @Jon sorry for late.Actually I realized after I submit my ans.Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Gautam3164: Ok, but why also change `$array1` in the process?

Comment: @Jon ;-)  .Ok edited.Just a glance that I considered his need.I think no need other than that.

Answer (score 2):

array key exists won't trigger notices

```
$sample = array('Strongly Agree' => 100);
$alternatives = array(   'Strongly Agree',    'Agree',    'Neither Agree or Disagree',    'Strongly Disagree');
$output=array();
foreach($alternatives as $alternative) {
    $output[$alternative] = array_key_exists($alternative, $sample)? $sample[$alternative]:0;
}

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$arr2 = array_merge(array_fill_keys($arr2, 0), $arr1);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/110345)